# Как записать выражение: если Explode делит значение по точке, то записать в новый массив

Tags: php, массивы

Как записать выражение: если Explode делит значение по точке, то записать в новый массив

```
for($i=0;$i<count($key);$i++) {
    if(explode('.',$key[$i])==true) {
        $mas[$i]=explode('.',$key[$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: да преобразуйте вы свои строки уже в формат .ini и с помощью parse_ini* сделайте свой массив

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
for($i=0;$i<count($key);$i++){
        if(strpos($key[$i], '.')){
             $mas[$i]=explode('.',$key[$i]);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Konstantin Choporov
Огромное спасибо
с помощью чего можно было бы проверить совпадает ли нулевой элемент каждого разделения предыдущему? и  как убрать если совпадает значение?